# How to make words appear in a list on the terminal?

Tags: java

Say I have this line of code here

`System.out.println("What is your favorite color 1=blue,2=green,3=yellow,4=orange,5=red,6=purple");`

It will print out this on the terminal

What is your favorite color 1=blue, 2=green, 3=yellow, 4=orange, 5=red, 6=purple

How would one make it to where it pops it out like this?

What is your favorite color?

1 = blue

2 = green

3 = yellow

etc...

Kind of like a list in the terminal but all from one line of code, I swear I used to know how but I can't remember and I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Use a newline character, `\n` i.e. `"Line1\nLine2\nLine3"`

Comment: Or call System.out.println() several times.

Comment: So like this `What is your favorite color?\n1 = blue\n2 = green\n3 = yellow`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Unix systems a line feed will suffice.

```
System.out.println("This is the first line\nThis is the second line");
```

However I believe that on Windows you will require a line feed and carriage return if my memory serves me best?

```
System.out.println("This is the first line\r\nThis is the second line");
```

Another solution, if you always expect to print a new line after a comma like you have specified in the question. You could replace your commas with new lines. I wouldn't typically recommend this solution but it will work in this case.

For example,

```
String colours = "1=blue,2=green,3=yellow";
colours = colours.replaceAll(",", "\n"); // Or \r\n
System.out.println(colours );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Test
public void testInput() throws NumberFormatException, IOException {

    final List<String> options = Arrays.asList("blue", "green", "yellow", "orange", "red", "purple");

    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("What is your favorite color\n");
    IntStream.range(0, options.size()).forEach(i -> sb.append(i).append("=").append(options.get(i)).append("\n"));

    System.out.println(sb.toString());

    final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    final int value = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
    if (value >= 0 && value < options.size()) {
        System.out.println("You choose " + options.get(value) + " (" + value + ")");
    } else {
        System.err.println("Invalid input (" + value + ")");
    }
}
```

as a more extended answer and using streams which looks cool - but a simple for loop does it also ;-)

Comment: Thankyou, thats how i write my code now but I'm trying to simplify this as much as possible because my friend is like just starting out in Java for school I figured it out though